# No Other User In Task Manager Users Tab Windows 7

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, task-manager, user

I want to ask why there is only me on Task Manager's Users tab.

Originally I wanted to be able to chat with other clients on my local network using msg command, but I can't found any other user.

How to see other users on the same network? I use Work Network, and all of the users is using wifi to connect.

I googled about it, but no information is close enough.

As much as a newbie question it sounded, I really appreciate any help.

Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 2):

The user tab is simply a way to view other sessions that are currently active on your computer (e.g. my server lists me twice - one locally, one remote)- not other users on the network.

If I understand what you are asking, the messaging component of Windows networking has not been there for some time - it started to become disabled in Windows XP SP1 (or 2) and was removed in Vista... Vista did come with an alternative local network messaging program, but, again it was removed in Windows 7.

If you Google "Winpopup", you can find MANY commercial/free alternatives.... I can't recommend any over any others though.

Comment: Yeah, the last time I ever saw it is in Windows 98 LOL. Thank you for your explanation, just to make it clear, there is no more local network messaging in Windows 7 right? I mean even if it's free it just wouldn't be the same.